# set table attribute value with other attribute values in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

i have this column in a table:

```
name = Column(String, default='ts-1')
```

how do i set the default value to increment automatically so that the names of objects will be 'ts-1', 'ts-2', 'ts-3'... when created.

i tried writing a constructor:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.name = 'ts-' + str(self.id)
```

but it always returns None.

thanks.

Comment: Have you try making a template with jinja2 or using exec?. These tools may help you do what you are looking for.

Comment: no im making a command line app

Answer (score 0):

I found a approach to solving this problem using sqlalchemy orm events. turns out to be fairly simple. the idea is to write an event listener on `init` so that it will be trigger whenever an object is created.

so now i can access the value of id of an instance.

```
from sqlalchemy import event

@event.listens_for(SomeClass, 'init')
    def change_name(target, args, kwargs):
    session.add(target)
    session.commit()
    target.name = 'sheet#' + str(target.id)
```